# Dúvida sobre vírgula nesta frase

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

A frase é:

> A criação e a aplicação do GPS, bem como a sua integração com os smartphones, nos possibilitou considerável avanço no quesito localização, fazendo o uso deste indispensável no dia-a-dia.

Estou estudando o uso de vírgulas e tenho algumas dúvidas nesta frase, são elas:

- As duas primeiras vírgulas estão lá pois estou listando algo relacionado ao GPS. Está correto desta forma ?
- A terceira vírgula coloquei pensando ser uma oração independente, mas não consigo ver o sentido desta oração sem o contexto previamente listado. Então a terceira vírgula seria plausível onde ela se encontra ?

Comment: Eu estou convencido que as tuas vírgulas estão corretas, mas tu hás de querer a razão alicerçada nos critérios formais da nossa gramática, e eu, quando o meu conhecimento desses critérios é insuficiente, sigo um critério diferente: digo a frase mentalmente, e vejo onde é que há pausas que precisem de ser assinaladas por vírgula; a maior parte das vezes isto concorda com os critérios formais. E concordo contigo que a última oração não é independente. Mas alguém te saberá explicar isto devidamente. Substituí foi duas vírgulas das tuas perguntas por pontos finais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vírgulas estão bem colocadas, porém há duas ocorrências que podem ser melhoradas.

A primeira é referente à concordância verbal.

> A criação e a aplicação do GPS, bem como a sua integração com os
>   smartphones, nos **possibilitaram** considerável avanço no quesito
>   localização (...)

E por fim, substituiria o gerúndio por outra forma.

> (...), **o que faz** o uso deste indispensável no dia-a-dia.

Comment: Oi Paulo. Não penso que seja correto afirmar que há gerundismo na frase original. O que faz você acreditar que foi excessivo?

Comment: @stafusa Apesar de aceitável, considero gerundismo porque a sentença não demonstra uma ação continua no tempo presente, mas sim uma ação atemporal. Por não depender do tempo, a forma infinitiva do verbo é a melhor indicada.

Comment: Mas "faz" é presente, não é atemporal - para manter o sentido original da frase talvez o passado pudesse ser usado: ", o que fez...". Talvez seja justamente o gerúndio que, na verdade, pode ser chamado de "atemporal" nessa frase, não?

Comment: Paulo e @stafusa, o gerúndio não tem de indicar ação durativa: "disse **piscando o olho**, enquanto elas entravam no carro: —Aquelas duas viram passarinho verde" (Machado de Assis); "E concluía **piscando o olho** ao commendador e **fazendo um gesto** intelligente para Felicia" (Camilo Castelo Branco); "O homem trabalhador — dizia ele, **piscando o olho** — soma; o preguiçoso diminui" (Erico Veríssimo). Também não é nada óbvio para mim que tenha de ser *possibilitaram* em vez de *possibilitou*. E as vírgulas estão vem colocadas porque...

Comment: @Jacinto Em todos os seus exemplos, o gerúndio indica uma ação continua no presente tempo em que outro evento acontecia ou acontece. O mesmo não se aplica ao exemplo do colega Matheus.

Comment: @stafusa Você tem razão. **Faz** é presente. Não que **fazendo** esteja errado ali, mas eu não o usaria e recomendo que não o use, diferente de os exemplos fornecidos pelo Jacinto.

Comment: Ah! Tu nestas situações piscas o olho continuamente? Então tá bem.

Comment: @Jacinto **A criação e a aplicação do GPS nos possibilitaram (...)**. Ao meu ver, trata-se de duas coisas distintas, daí o uso do plural.

Comment: @Jacinto O que eu quis dizer foi: uma ação que acontece enquanto outra ação acontece.

Comment: A verdade é que a gente está trabalhando demais uma frase que, para início de conversa, não é muito boa. Por exemplo, "avanço no quesito localização" deveria ser reescrito, na minha opinião.

Comment: Tens razão. Não tinha prestado devida atenção a "a criação e a aplicação". Quanto à falta de simultaneidade das ações, não é por aí que o gato vai às filhoses: "Mr. Richard vacilou a esta pergunta, **dizendo depois**: — Quase evidentes" (Júlio Dinis); "saltou para fora, **cerrando depois** a janela" (Joaquim Manuel de Macedo); "abre automaticamente a caixa, queima os bilhetes e perde a chave, **aparecendo depois** a caixa fechada" (Machado de Assis).

Comment: Eu não substituiria *fazendo* por *que fez/faz*: não fica claro qual é o antecedente do *que*. Prefiro a sugestão do @stafusa: *o que fez/faz*. Mas mesmo isto não é equivalente ao original. Equivalente ao origina é "A criação e a aplicação do GPS, bem como a sua integração com os smartphones, nos possibilitou considerável avanço no quesito localização, **e fez/faz** o uso deste indispensável no dia-a-dia."

Comment: Paulo, se estiveres interessado, estes usos do gerúndio vêm todos descritos na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* do Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (cap. verbo--emprego do gerúndio): o gerúndio pode exprimir, relativamente ao tempo da ação da oração principal, uma ação imediatamente anterior, uma ação contemporânea, ou uma "ação posterior e equivale, na maioria das vezes, a uma oração coordenada iniciada pela conjunção *e*". "vacilou a esta pergunta, dizendo depois"= "... e disse depois"; "a aplicação do GPS ... nos possibilitou ..., fazendo" = "..., e fez/faz".

Comment: @Jacinto, Tantos anos ouvindo dos professores para evitar o uso de gerúndio a torto direito, que tudo me parece gerundismo. Alterei minha resposta, optando pela sugestão de stafusa. Aceito o uso do gerúndio, em que "fazendo" seja equivalente a "e fez/faz", o que não estava claro pra mim.

Comment: Paulo, fui ver (de novo) o que é esse gerundismo, e os exemplos de uso criticado que vi é dizer-se, por exemplo, *vou estar jantando* quando o que se quer dizer é simplesmente *vou jantar*. O uso do gerúndio da pergunta já existia no português medieval.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu me refiro ao Português no contexto contemporâneo e da língua como forma de expressão da arte. Reconheço que o gerúndio foi empregado de forma correta, porém não gosto da forma enrolada como soa a frase.